Self-induction in a permanent magnet
when a permanent magnet is moved in a coil, an emf is induced in the coil. so is an emf also induced in the magnet itself? and if not then why not. and if I replace this permanent magnet with a electromagnet with  constant dc supply and move it inside another coil does an emf get induced in this electromagnet ( i dont mean the coil itself, as that is already established ) and if in all those cases it is a no, then when does self-inductance occur exactly?
